How to add a type hint to a variable representing self in a static method within a class
I'm trying to add type hints to a static method in Python using typing.Self. However, the type hint isn't being applied to the self argument within the function itself.
from typing import Self

class Vect:
    x: float
    y: float

    @staticmethod
    def angle(v1: Self, v2: Self):
        return math.acos(v1 * v2 / v1.magnitude() / v2.magnitude())

The code is working but it doesn't give me any type hints in the angle method for variables v1 and v2.

In this case, a @staticmethod is not the best choice. Perhaps it should just be a normal method, which can be typed simply as def angle(self, other: Self) -> float.

If you need this kind of API for whatever reason, use @classmethod, not @staticmethod.

typing.Self is meant to be used for instance methods returning self, or class methods that are alternative constructors, but static methods do not have a self or cls parameter.
One way to type hint a static method is using forward references, that allows type hinting names not yet defined.
Solution
from typing import Self

class Vect:
    x: float
    y: float

    @staticmethod
    def angle(v1: 'Vect', v2: 'Vect'):
        return math.acos(v1 * v2 / v1.magnitude() / v2.magnitude())


One alternative worth mentioning is using from __future__ import annotations and typing with class itself - angle(v1: Vect, v2: Vect)

You cannot use Self in a static method. By definition, a static method doesn't take self as a parameter.
So, make it a normal method
import math
from typing import Self

class Vect:
    x: float
    y: float

    def angle(self, v1: Self, v2: Self):
        return math.acos(v1 * v2 / v1.magnitude() / v2.magnitude())


It doesn't make much sense for this method to require 3 instances of the object, but the initial explanation is correct - Self typing is invalid for @staticmethods, as they are not inherently bound to the class they are in.
